# Indentation with "#." start of paragraph

Tags: formatting

When I type `1. blah blah blah` Vim recognizes the `1.` prefix and it indents the rest of the paragraph tidy.

I would like to configure Vim to do the same thing with `#.` literal prefix, since ReST files autonumbers the paragraphs when started with `#.`.

In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907651/indentation-with-start-of-paragraph?noredirect=1#29907651) I got suggested this:

```
let &formatlistpat = '^\s*\%(\d\+\|#\)[\]:.)}\t ]\s*'
```

I added this to my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.rst let &formatlistpat = '^\s*\%(\d\+\|#\)[\]:.)}\t ]\s*'
```

It doesn't work. In fact, I modified the regexp and Vim seems to ignore anything I put there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`:help 'formatlistpat'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27flp%27) says:

> A pattern that is used to recognize a list header.  This is used for the "n" flag in 'formatoptions'.

And [`:help 'formatoptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fo%27) says:

> Vim default: "tcq"

[`:help fo-table`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table) describes the meaning of the `n` flag:

> n              When formatting text, recognize numbered lists.  This actually uses the `'formatlistpat'` option, thus any kind of list can be used.
>   [..rest snipped..]

So I suspect it's probably a matter of just adding this flag to `formatoptions`. To add the flag, use:

```
set formatoptions+=n
```

Comment: In fact this actually work. THANKS!. But I wonder if the "default" behaviour can be modified without doing this. That is, VIM without "n" in ```formatoptions``` already recognize some numbered list formats. Is that hardcoded in the code?

Comment: @jcea It doesn't work with me when I test it with `1. ` ...  Perhaps this is something in your specific filetype?